# jhipster mvnw command not working in jenkins only

Tags: maven, jenkins, jhipster

I'm trying to do Continuous Integration for the **Jhipster** project using **Jenkins** CI. In Jenkins I created as a pipeline project and tried to build with the following `Jenkinsfile`,

```
node {
    stage('checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    // uncomment these 2 lines and edit the name 'node-4.6.0' according to what you choose in configuration
    // def nodeHome = tool name: 'node-4.6.0', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    // env.PATH = "${nodeHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    stage('check tools') {
        sh "node -v"
        sh "npm -v"
        sh "bower -v"
        sh "gulp -v"
    }

    stage('npm install') {
        sh "npm install"
    }

    stage('clean') {
        sh "mvnw clean"
    }

    stage('backend tests') {
        try {
            sh "mvnw test"
        } catch(err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
        }
    }

    stage('frontend tests') {
        try {
            sh "gulp test"
        } catch(err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/test-results/karma/TESTS-*.xml'])
        }
    }

    stage('packaging') {
        sh "mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests"
    }
}
```

It works fine upto npm install, on `clean` stage it get failure with error `mvnw: command not found`. I have tried with ***mvn clean*** it works but **mvnw** command is not working.

Also I have tried with ***'./mvnw clean'***, this tries to download something from maven and fails because of connection timeout.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I run the same command in cmd and its working but in jenkins not working

Comment: It's not linux, I'm working on Windows machine

Comment: I don't have any experience with Jenkins on Windows,  './mvnw clean' looks like unix command style. Anyway mvnw should download maven binaries, if it fails because of connection timeout then there's something wrong on your machine (maybe a firewall)

Comment: I have added proxy in Jenkins, what else should I need to make it work

Comment: Have you tried to run same command manually from your jenkins machine?